# function from service is undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement an async validator in angular with devextreme components. For this, I defined a service with a function. Then I import this service into the appropriate component, define a property in the constructor and then call the function. But I get the error, that `this.asyncval is undefined`. Why?

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxpopup-et6z3y

Just click the new partner button, write some text in the name field and then hit tab and review the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is bound in the template. So it might lose the reference to `this` keyword. Instead of a named function, you could use an anonymous function

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  alreadyExists = (params) => this.asyncval.alreadyExists(params.value);
  ...
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxpopup-ggnc1z).

Comment: Thank you again for your help. It works now as expected. And I learned the topics 'this' in connection with 'arrow functions'.